# WildFly 13 datasource getConnection(user, password) doesn't work

Tags: java, jdbc, wildfly, datasource

Using WildFly 13.
I'm trying to get a java.sql.Connection from the datasource that is being defined in stadalone.xml, as so:

```
ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/myDS");
connection = ds.getConnection(user, password);
```

The above always fails with  `Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031016: Wrong credentials passed to getConnection`, while

```
ds.getConnection()
```

works just fine and can retrieve the connection.
Moreover, when getting and inspecting the metadata from the connection retrieved via the no args call, the user and password seem to be the same that I'm passing to the method with arguments but which fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasource's pool section must include the true attribute in order for this to work.